# Google trend chart not showing

Tags: javascript, html

I want to display google trend chart inside my HTML but problem is however i got my Embed javascript from google trend page its not working on my local machine. My goal is to display chart of last 12 month data on any specific keywords. How can i achieve this?

[image: Screen shot]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ssl.gstatic.com/trends_nrtr/1173_RC01/embed_loader.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript"> trends.embed.renderExploreWidget("TIMESERIES", {"comparisonItem":[{"keyword":"arts","geo":"","time":"today 12-m"}],"category":0,"property":""}, {"exploreQuery":"q=arts&date=today 12-m","guestPath":"https://trends.google.co.in:443/trends/embed/"}); </script> 


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're just cutting off the bottom. Try defining the minimum body height to be 450px in your css or html (~ size of Google's embed)

```
<body style="min-height: 450px">
```

Comment: No this is not the case. even if i put this code on body still not displays data

Comment: Add  iframe Id min-height instead of Body Height:       Ex:- #trends-widget-1 {
    min-height: 450px;
}